# How to set default precision for double and float values while reading the file in Azure Data Flow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have a Double cols having values like

206.00695355284904 . But I dont have idea how much is the precision here.But i need the precision of 15 from the level of reading the source itself.
It Should not convet them to Exponential notation . Please how can i achieve this in Azure data flow reading the input file.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the below approach using **CAST** transformation To get the **206.006953552849** exact precision in Azure data flow.
**Source:**
[image]

**CAST Transformation in Data flow**

I have used a **CAST** transformation and cast as **STRING**

If you want the 206.006953552849 value exact you can use STRING data type.
[image]

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: I think its bot what i needed exactly. For example if i had two double cols having 234.23333333433333 and 234.2333333343 when i do a col1 -Col2 , It doesnot give me 0 instead it goes to negetive or some other val. if the numbers were of same precision , i should get 0. Thasts what the requirement is.

Comment: @AzSuryaTeja When you are using decimal numbers for subtraction the maximum scale i.e., the maximum numbers after decimal will be a maximum of the scale of either of the minuend or subtrahend.
in this case the difference between the numbers has a scale more than the max of either minuend or subtrahend.
Hence as per ADF it is taking as exponential value.
e1 - e2 max(s1, s2) + max(p1 - s1, p2 - s2) + 1 max(s1, s2)
refer to this Microsoft documentation  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16